# Emacs: How to delete a line starting with specific text

Tags: search, replace, emacs

How can I find and delete lines which start with the text `in`?

I use the command `C-M-s ^in` to find all lines starting with `in`, but then I don't really know what to do.

Answer (score 11):

**`M-x flush-lines RET ^in RET`**

`C-h f flush-lines` tells you:

> **`flush-lines`** is an interactive compiled Lisp function in `replace.el`.
>
> It is bound to `menu-bar edit flush-lines`.
>
> `(flush-lines REGEXP &optional RSTART REND INTERACTIVE)`
>
> Delete lines containing matches for `REGEXP`.
>
> When called from Lisp (and usually when called interactively as
>   well, see below), applies to the part of the buffer after point.
>   The line point is in is deleted if and only if it contains a
>   match for regexp starting after point.
>
> If `REGEXP` contains upper case characters (excluding those preceded by `\`)
>   and `search-upper-case` is non-`nil`, the matching is case-sensitive.
>
> Second and third arg `RSTART` and `REND` specify the region to operate on.
>   Lines partially contained in this region are deleted if and only if
>   they contain a match entirely contained in it.
>
> Interactively, in Transient Mark mode when the mark is active, operate
>   on the contents of the region.  Otherwise, operate from point to the
>   end of (the accessible portion of) the buffer.  When calling this function
>   from Lisp, you can pretend that it was called interactively by passing
>   a non-nil `INTERACTIVE` argument.
>
> If a match is split across lines, all the lines it lies in are deleted.
>   They are deleted **before** looking for the next match.  Hence, a match
>   starting on the same line at which another match ended is ignored.

Comment: And for anyone who wasn't aware of either, the `keep-lines` command complements `flush-lines`. They are both very useful.

Comment: @phils: Yes. And it might help to remember them, or to rediscover them later, by their aliases: `delete-matching-lines` and `delete-non-matching-lines`.

Comment: Is there anyway to interactively delete matching lines from the whole buffer, without losing your current place?

Comment: @NetMage: `C-SPC`, to set a mark at point. Then `M-<` to go to bob. Then flush. Then `C-u C-SPC` to go back where you were.

Comment: That's annoying :) Surprised all the point/region commands don't take an argument to do the whole buffer.

Comment: @NetMage: It is simple to write a command that does what you want. And since you ask to do it "interactively", even without a command you can do that with `M-: (flush-lines REGEXP nil (buffer-size) t)`, where `REGEXP` is the regexp you want to match.

Answer (score 2):

query-replace-regexp "in.*" to "" will be work. you should not input " to the prompt

Comment: flush-lines is better

Comment: It will give an empty line. But what if I want to delete the full line itself without leaving an empty line?

Comment: @vineeshvs use flush-lines and input the ^in.* regex after the prompt.